# Is there any way to use electric pieces in Stud.io?

Tags: electronics, remote-control, bricklink-studio

[image: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCh8XjIuJVnEluRYegGrNSuQ]

Also is the stack exchange meant for digital LEGO editors like Stud.io?

Comment: Hi "Technic Axlerod" and welcome to Bricks.SE! Please take the [tour] and check out the [help] pages to learn more about what questions are on topic in this StackExchange site - spoiler alert: your question is absolutely on topic ;) Have fun and play well!